# Trouble figuring out a segmentation fault on a function call

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector

Still new to c++ so I apologize if this is really obvious or something. Currently I have a small program (~250 lines) throwing a segmentation fault. There's a small amount of recursion within `someFunction()` but its throwing the error on its call. Below is a shortened version of the code throwing the error, this mock-up doesn't throw the error so I'm not sure if its a pointer error, or a memory error. I already checked my memory limit and I don't think that's the issue. Any help pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Solved it, it appears it was an issue with how much memory the array of objects in objectA was taking up.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class objectA {
    //contains two other object arrays, a few other objects, and a few other variables
};

class objectB {
public:
    vector<objectA> aObjectA;
    void someFunction(int x, int y, string z, vector<objectA> aObjectA) {
    //do something
}
    void setVectorFunction() {
    //sets the vector with currently only 1 aObjectA
}
};


int main() {
objectB aObjectB;
aObjectB.setVectorFunction();
aObjectB.someFunction(0, 0, "0000,0000", aObjectB.aObjectA);
cout << "Test";
}
```

Comment: If the mockup doesn't exhibit the problem, why do you think anyone can tell from it what your problem is?

Comment: Passing in a copy of the object's vector to a non-static function of the object looks a bit strange. Please, [mcve]

Comment: If this is Linux run it under valgrind.

Comment: I suspect that your amount of recursion isn't quite as small as you believe.

Comment: Are  objectA's class member values plain c ++ arrays? Has objectA class copy constructor? If does, does it copy arrays explicitly? Does it copy all it's members explicitly?

Comment: Leaving this up to help future people but in 'objectA' there was a few arrays of objects, changed the sizes of the arrays to [1] and ran the code and it removed the error, so maybe it was a out of memory error?

Comment: As Mr. Spock would say: passing a class member, explicitly, to a method of its own class is highly illogical. Mr. Spock would also say: passing large vectors to a function, by value, is also very illogical.

Comment: Storing a vector of stack objects, that have arrays of objects (I suppose that array values are stack objects too) as member values, is very **BAD** idea...